# tx().commit() not working in python gremlin

Tags: python-2.7, gremlin, janusgraph

In Python code i am trying to delete vertex from janusgraph and commit thereafter. But the code g.tx().commit() is returning - "exceptions.AttributeError: 'GraphTraversalSource' object has no attribute 'tx'".
Am i missing any imports .Please suggest

I have tried without commit but the vertex simply stays there with out returning any error from code

commit works fine while using gremlin console.issue is observed from code

g.tx().commit()

exceptions.AttributeError: 'GraphTraversalSource' object has no attribute 'tx'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gremlinpython is a Gremlin Language Variant which translates your Gremlin into bytecode and submits that to a remote server for execution. Once on the server, the transaction is considered "managed" in the sense that each requests automatically starts a transaction and then when the request process is complete the server either commits the transaction if successful or rolls it back if there was a failure. As you have found, you can not (and do not need to) call `g.tx()` from gremlinpython directly.

Please consider reading through the TinkerPop [Introduction](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#intro) documentation for more information.

Comment: But  a drop() command without commit() is not throwing any error- at the same time the vertex is not getting deleted as well .How to drop this vertex now

Comment: Please update your question to include the code you use to create "g" (i.e. the `GraphTraversalSource`) and explain the method by which you `drop()` and check for deletion. Thanks

Comment: graph = Graph()
        connection = DriverRemoteConnection('ws://<IP>:8182/gremlin', 'g')
        g = graph.traversal().withRemote(connection)
 g.V().has("foo",1).drop()

Comment: try `g.V().has("foo",1).drop().iterate()` - you probably need to iterate your traversal: http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/tutorials/the-gremlin-console/#result-iteration

Comment: For gremlinpython, understand the question regarding is asked in the context of bytecode-based traversals. For string-based scripts submitted via the gremlin driver client, does your answer (that there's no need to call `g.tx().commit()`) apply too? I tried submitting `g.tx().commit()` via the string-based scripts and there are no errors.

Comment: if you are using scripts, you can call `g.tx().commit()` but there is little need unless you are using unmanaged sessions. transactions will be automatically committed/rolled-back for you otherwise. I suppose you might have multiple transactions within a single request that might call for you to do that but it seems a bit atypical.